# Round to "beautiful" value

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, floating-point, int

guys, I'm making simple graph drawer and want to find beautiful values for horizontal lines.
For example, if I have value equals to 72089.601562, beautiful is 70000, or 75000. So, I think that beautifulNumber%5 = 0.
Have you any ideas?

Comment: you want to round to the nearest 5,000th?

Comment: Methinks [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Fou…) would work.

Comment: Rounding should be dynamic. For example 7 should transform to 10.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
#import <math.h>
#import <stdio.h>

#define ROUNDING 5000

int beautify(float input)
{
    // Cast to int, losing the decimal value.
    int value = (int)input;

    value = (value / ROUNDING) * ROUNDING;

    if ((int)input % ROUNDING > ROUNDING / 2 )
    {
        value += ROUNDING;
    }

    return value;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", beautify(70000.601562)); // 70000
    printf("%d\n", beautify(72089.601562)); // 70000
    printf("%d\n", beautify(76089.601562)); // 75000
    printf("%d\n", beautify(79089.601562)); // 80000
    printf("%d\n", beautify(70000.601562)); // 70000

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. The function `beatify` is plain C, which you can use in your Objective-C project. Remember that Objective-C is just C with some additions. If you want you can make it into an Obj-C method, but there is no need really. You can keep it as a C function, just place it outside your class.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you want a floor value, a ceiling value or just to round to the nearest 5000.

For a floor value:

`int beautiful = (int)(floor(ugly / 5000.0) * 5000.0);`

For a ceiling value:

`int beautiful = (int)(ceil(ugly / 5000.0) * 5000.0);`

For rounding:

`int beautiful = (int)(round(ugly / 5000.0) * 5000.0);`

For making graph lines, I'd probably find the minimum and maximum values you have to graph, start with a floor value for the minimum value and then add your desired interval until you have surpassed your maximum value.

For instance:

```
float minValue = 2.34;
float maxValue = 7.72;
int interval = 1;
NSMutableArray *horizLines = [NSMutableArray array];
int line = (int)(floor(minValue / interval) * interval);
[horizLines addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:line]];
do {
    line = (int)(ceil(minValue / interval) * interval);
    [horizLines addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:line]];
    if (minValue >= maxValue) break;
    minValue = minValue + interval;
}
```

Use as needed!

Comment: If ugly number is 0.3, for example, will it work? I think, that no.

Comment: What do you mean it "won't work"? In your example you were talking about rounding by 5000, and that's what his examples do.

Comment: I want dynamic rounding for all numbers. From 0.0000000003 to 99999

Comment: There's a problem with that request: it's far too open-ended. Do you want a linear graph or a logarithmic one? What if your min value is 0.0004 and your max value is 9999? Which one is used to create the beautiful intervals? And can we assume you want the "nearest 5", no matter what the level of precision is? And, do you just want the "nearest 5" above and below a certain number, or, as your question states, are you graphing values, which would indicate multiple values?

Comment: Example of my graph: http://cl.ly/GF01 http://cl.ly/GFZJ http://cl.ly/GFq8 And some examples of ugly values you can see on the left side. I want to make it beautiful

Comment: I'm just glad that beautiful isn't a subjective thing, that makes it a whole lot easier! For the most beautiful rounding, just convert the value to PI. Mathematicians will agree that the value would become one of the most beautiful out there!

Comment: Yes, it's subjective, but numbers on screenshot is very ugly. It should be short and simple to understand.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't have a firm grasp on how to define "beautiful". If we can't have an exact formula, how can I write code? Would "beautiful" upper and lower bounds for 0.03 be 0.00 and 0.05? For 1.342, would it be 1.0 and 1.5 or 0 and 5? Or 1.30 and 1.35? Or 1.340 and 1.345?

Comment: I think, that it should be something like this: 1. We have number, for example: 0.00064; 2. Found first not nil value (6); 3. Convert it to beautiful value (beautifulValue%5 = 0);

Comment: This still doesn't answer what exactly beautiful is. Please, at least try to describe the curve of beautiful values.

Comment: For values, like 564, we should find first to numbers (56) and convert it to be beautiful, other should be nil. For example: ugly - 56694076, beautiful - 55000000

Comment: May be "beautiful" isn't correct word. Have you ever seen graphs in internet? Values on left side is pretty simple and it's very simple to "read" graph.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like you'd want it to scale based on the size of the number. If the range only goes to 10, then obviously rounding to the nearest 5,000 doesn't make sense. There's probably a really elegant way to code it using bit shifting but just something like this will do the trick:

```
float value = 72089.601562
int beautiful = 0;

// EDIT to support returning a float for small numbers:
if (value < 0.2) beautiful = int(value*100)/100.;
else if (value < 2.) beautiful = int(value*10)/10.;

// Anything bigger is easy:
else if (value < 20) beautiful = (int)value;
else if (value < 200) beautiful = (int)value/10;
else if (value < 2000) beautiful = (int)value/100;
else if (value < 20000) beautiful = (int)value/1000;
// etc
```

Comment: it returns full number, but it should be divisible by 5, and your method isn't working for very little numbers. For example: 0.042. Beautiful for it: 0.05

Comment: see edit for support of returning a rounded beautiful float for small numbers

Comment: what the hell is a "full value"?

Comment: sorry for my english. Full value is rounded value (round() function).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to do is round to 1 or perhaps 2 significant digits.  Rounding to n significant digits is pretty easy:

```
double roundToNDigits(double x, int n) {
    double basis = pow(10.0, floor(log10(x)) - (n-1));
    return basis * round(x / basis);
}
```

This will give you `roundToNDigits(74518.7, 1) == 70000.0` and `roundToNDigits(7628.54, 1) == 8000.00`

If you want to round to 1 or 2 digits (only 2 where the second digit is 5), you want something like:

```
double roundSpecial(double x) {
    double basis = pow(10.0, floor(log10(x))) / 2.0;
    return basis * round(x / basis);
}
```